# How to run sqlplus query in python 3.4

Tags: python, oracle, sqlite, select, python-3.x

I' m new to python and I am trying to figure out how I can connect to remote oracle DB  and run a select query using a python script. Here is what i am trying to achieve:

```
1) Connect to oracle db and run select query
2) Write the result to the file.
```

This is the regular connection string I use:

```
sqlplus temapp/'password'@temappdb
and then I use a select query, lets say select * from employees where employ_id=12;
```

Not quite sure how to implement this in python 3.4, in 2.7 MySQLdb module/library is being used.

```
    **Here is my blueprint:** 
    #!/bin/python

    import sqlite3
    import sys
    import os

config = {
  'user': 'user',
  'password': '*****',
  'host': '127.0.0.1',
  'database': 'test',
  'raise_on_warnings': True,
}
    conn = sqlite3.connect('config') # not sure how to pass user and password
    c = conn.cursor()
    c.execute('select * from employees where employ_id=12')
```

2) And I have no idea how to write it in the file, my first guess was to manipulate with stdin and stdout by I believe there is a more efficient way to do it.

```
orig_stdout = sys.stdout
out = open("/output.txt", 'w')
sys.stdout = out

c.execute('select * from employees where employ_id=12')
sys.stdout = orig_stdout
out.close()
```

Can someone please advise on the better solution ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need a working Oracle Client or Instant Client installation and the cx_Oracle module.

Then try this:

```
import cx_Oracle
import csv

con = cx_Oracle.connect('temapp/password@temappdb')
cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM emp")

with open("emp.csv", "wb") as csv_file:
    csv_writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
    csv_writer.writerow([i[0] for i in cur.description])  # write headers
    csv_writer.writerows(cur)
```